# nethunter commands not found

Tags: android, termux

i just installed `nethunter` on android. i installed full arm64. everything worked the first time around. after installing a few other packages, i am no longer able to connect to `nethunter`. when i am in the local and enter try to use the `nethunter` commands it says, `"nethunter: command not found"`.

any help would be appreciated thanks.

i have already tried to reinstall everything again but i was unable to solve the issue